# Is it save to delete the akonadi file_db_data?

Tags: kde, akonadi

I don't use kmail on my Ubuntu anymore. I use Thunderbird now.

still I have this 1.6GB large file

```
~/.local/share/akonadi/file_db_data
```

I only guess, it is so large, cause my IMAP folder is about that size and It was created, when I tried out kmail.

Is that file needed for anything else than kmail?

If I would remove the whole akonadi-server with

```
apt-get remove --purge kmail akonadi-server
```

would that delete anything I could still use although I don't use KDE anymore?

For example, I still use krusader and some passwords stored there seem to come from the kde-wallet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: things that reside in `~/.local/` in a sub-directory belong to the software that the directory is named after. `file_db_data` belongs to `akonadi` so deleting the file will affect `akonadi`. If you do not care about that anymore it is safe to delete both the file and the directory.

This:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kmail akonadi-server
```

should also remove that directory and the file. It will not delete krusader.

Answer (score 0):

> The Akonadi database is NOT your MAIN data storage. Even if it gets destroyed, removed, your data is still safe.

https://blogs.kde.org/node/4503

However, if you'll still use Akonadis functionality and you really need the disk space, I would instead recommend to uncouple unneeded data sources (IMAP mail folders etc) and execute this command: `akonadictl vacuum`